# Send extra attribute from CKFinder to CKEditor 5

Tags: javascript, python, ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckfinder3

My goal is simple: I want to add extra attributes to an `img` tag in `CKEditor`; e.g.: `<img src="path" data-attr="myattr">`.

I built my Python connector; I added my upcast/downcast to CKE, but I still don't fully understand how to send the `data-attr` attribute from `CKFinder` to `CKEditor`.

Pipeline should be:

- Click `CKFinder`
- Select an image — this should contain an extra attribute: e.g.: `data-attr`
- Add the image to `CKEditor` — the tag should contain the `data-attr` attribute

I can't figure how to do the last two steps. Any suggestions?